# Mathematics teaching position in the UK

Tags: career-path, job, job-search

I hold a PhD in pure mathematics and am looking for mathematics teaching positions in the UK, preferably at University level.

1. What would be some websites where to find such ads?
2. What is the standard application procedure/requirements? When are the deadlines for applications? When are the offers typically made?

*A note on question#2:*

I would be interested in finding out whether there are any general comments one could make regarding the application/selection process by analogy to the US postdoc application system outlined in the next sentences. In the US, in order to apply for a postdoc position [research and teaching] one typically needs to submit 3 research recommendations, 1 teaching recommendation, a research statement, a teaching statement, cv, cover letter. Most deadlines are around November, December, January and I believe most offers are made in January - early February.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you stick to just one question per SE post.

Comment: I have just edited the question to fit the rules in the help center. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Academic jobs in the UK are usually advertised on [jobs.ac.uk](http://jobs.ac.uk) website, but there are of course many others. Typically, you will be asked to submit your application online, including application form, cv, supporting documents and details of your references. Answers to other questions are more specific to each position. You may wish to familiarize yourself with the positions currently advertised on the website, to get a sense of the job market at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Such jobs are also sometimes posted on the [site of the European Mathematical Society](http://www.euro-math-soc.eu/jobs) and on the mathematics departments webpages of the universities.

Comment: Thanks to Dmitry Savostyanov and Fabrice Baudoin for the very helpful advice. I would still appreciate any related comments/advice.

Comment: In particular, I would still be interested to read answers from persons who currently hold [or held in the past] such teaching positions.

Comment: I would also be interested in finding out whether there are any general comments one could make regarding the application/selection process. For instance, in the US there is a fairly standard application process for postdoc positions [research and teaching]: 3 research recommendations, 1 teaching recommendation, a research statement, a teaching statement, cv, cover letter; most deadlines are around November, December, January and I believe most offers are made in January - early February. My question is: could one make similar ``general'' statements regarding the teaching positions in the UK?

Comment: @user1451857, it would be good if you could edit your question to include your last comment.